# JVM process - print every method argument

Tags: java, debugging, btrace

We use InstallAnywhere to create installers. Recently an installer created using it started failing with StackOverFlow error (in silent installation).. Error stack has thousands of lines like below.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableManager.substitute(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableFacade.substitute(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableFacade.substitute(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.magicfolders.MagicFolder.getPath(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.magicfolders.MagicFolder.toString(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableManager.getValueOfVariable(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.IAVariableStringResolver.getValueOfVariable(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableManager.substitute(Unknown Source)
```

VariableManager.substitute is very common API, it takes a string argument and return substituted(evaluted) value.  How can I see the argument passed to it in the real JVM process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a [btrace script.](https://btrace.kenai.com/)

The installer process is Java process that can be queried by JVM tools like (jps, jstack)

1. Install JDK (JVisualVM comes with it)
2. Start VisualVM and Install btrace plugin

[image]

3. Right click on process (LAX) Start 'btrace'

[image]

Copy following btrace script to btrace console

```
package com.sun.btrace.samples;

import com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils;
import com.sun.btrace.Profiler;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import com.sun.btrace.*;

@BTrace class Profiling {
@Property
Profiler swingProfiler = BTraceUtils.Profiling.newProfiler();

@OnMethod(
    clazz="com.zerog.ia.installer.util.VariableFacade", 
    method="/.*substitute.*/")
    void entry( String probeMethod) {
        BTraceUtils.print("Entry" );
        BTraceUtils.println(BTraceUtils.timestamp() );
        BTraceUtils.println(probeMethod);
    }

@OnMethod(
    clazz="com.zerog.ia.installer.*", 
    method="/.*/")
    void entry2( @ProbeMethodName(fqn=true) String probeMethod ) {
        BTraceUtils.print("Entry" );
        BTraceUtils.println(BTraceUtils.timestamp() );
        BTraceUtils.println(probeMethod);
    }

@OnMethod(clazz = "com.zerog.ia.installer.*", method = "/.*/", location = @Location(Kind.RETURN))
     void onPrepareReturn(AnyType arg) {
        if (arg != null) {
             BTraceUtils.println(arg);
        }
    }

}
```

Start btrace by clicking "**start**" icon.
[image]

Watch output for logs.

Btrace is extremely powerful tool to quickly check inside the JVM. Checkout more at [Btrace Kenai project](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace/pages/UserGuide)

Edit-comment from @J.B
[Btrace is now at github](https://github.com/jbachorik/btrace)

Comment: FYI: The active BTrace project location is GitHub (https://github.com/jbachorik/btrace)

Comment: :) and that is yours?

Comment: Well, both are mine :) It's just that Kenai.com is really not supported anymore and I decided to move the project to GitHub not to become marooned when they decide to pull the plug.

Comment: @ J.B: Great.  your btrace is a super-cool and super-useful for any Java developer..

Comment: @ J.B:  I guess my answer is not complete. If you can provide an answer for "how to print all argument" that will make this page more useful. I will then change the answer to yours..